# I get Bad Request every time i try to create an azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm still new in Azure.

Today, I try to create an azure function instance
but, everytime I try to create one I get a Bad Request Error

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Cannot update the site '{project-name}' because it uses x64 worker process which is not allowed in the target compute mode.",
        "details": [
            {
                "message": "Cannot update the site '{project-name}' because it uses x64 worker process which is not allowed in the target compute mode."
            },
            {
                "code": "BadRequest"
            },
            {}
        ]
    }
}
```

I have no idea what it does mean. So, can you give me an Idea what's wrong? and How I supposed to do to fix it?.

Comment: What runtime stack and plan are you creating this on?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara I use F1 App Service Plan, for the stack i use Node 14 on Linux

Comment: 64-bit architecture isn't supported on [Free/Shared tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits). You'll need Basic or higher.

Answer (score 1):

The [Free/Shared tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits) only support 32-bit application architecture. You'll need **Basic or higher** to use 64-bit.